# Is it possible to see the live rendering effect of PhantomJS?

Tags: phantomjs

PhantomJS is a very cool tool for taking screenshots. But since it doesn't tell you how your HTML renders like until you save the image, it's quite tough to adjust small details with it. Is there any way to make the process easier?

For example, to output the display of the page rendered by PhantomJS live to somewhere so that I can see how it actually renders.

Thanks,

Comment: You still have to start the PhantomJS process anew, don't you? What does the additional opening of the resulting screenshot going to cost you? Perhaps you should look into an image viewer which supports live reload if it senses that the image has changed.

Comment: I found a place shouldn't be rendered as the screenshot tells, and I want to adjust the css while I can see the rendering output.